# Rationalize the fraction

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

How do rationalize the following fraction:

$$\frac{1} {\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^{1/k_i}}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Some more context would be helpful as well as some code indicating what you have already tried.

Comment: Did you mean to ask this question on [math.se]? This is a site for the computing software *Mathematica*.

Comment: For each $x(i)^{\frac{1}{k(i)}}$ ,it should times $x(i)^{\frac{k(i)-1}{k(i)}}$ to get x(i)

Answer (score 1):

```
    1/Sum[Subscript[x, i]^(1/Subscript[k, i]), {i, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: @A_user_with_NoName. Is there a better way in mathematica to rationalize this fraction. Many thanks.